# Splunk lookup table returns empty result

Tags: splunk

I have a simple lookup table as following

[image]

But when I lookup the table it returns empty results

```
| makeresults 
| eval ip="10.10.10.10"
| lookup my_test ip as ip output info as info
```

[image]

What was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the my_test lookup defined?  By default, Splunk lookup tables perform strict text-matching searches.  "10.10.10.10" does not match "10.10.10.10/32" so `lookup` returns nothing.

To match CIDR addresses, the lookup must be defined to use them on specific fields.  Go to Settings->Lookups->Lookup definitions and select my_test.  Tick the "Advanced options" box and enter "CIDR(ip)" in the "Match type" box.  Then click Save.

Comment: Ah damn, I didn't check CIDR!